# NextAuth GetServerSession JWT Session Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to secure one of my API routes in my NextJS application, however I keep receiving a JWT Session Error. This has been quite annoying because I am building out a pretty simple use case and I didn't think I was using JWT at all. From what I could find of the [next-auth documentation](https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#securing-api-routes), securing an api endpoint seemed quite easy. Below are snippets of my code.

Using "next-auth": "^4.24.5", "react": "18.2.0",

## pages/api/reviews

Here, I tried to secure the PUT endpoint

```
import pool from "../../../backend-utils";
import { getServerSession } from "next-auth/next";
import { authOptions } from "../auth/[...nextauth]";

export default async function handler(req, res){

    const method = req.method;
      
    if (method == "GET"){
    try{
        const client = await pool.connect()
        const data = await client.query('SELECT * FROM reviews;');
        res.status(200).json({ body: data });
    catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({message: "There was an error and we could not complete your get all reviews request. Error: "+ error});
     }
    else if (method == "PUT"){
        try{

            const session = await getServerSession(req, res, authOptions);
            if (!session) {
                return res.status(500).json({ message: 'The request was unauthorized' });
            }

            const {rest_name, o_rating, price, taste, experience, description, city, state_code} = JSON.parse(req.body);
            const response = await pool.query(`INSERT INTO reviews(rest_name, o_rating, price, taste, experience, description, city, state_code, user_id_submitted, soph_submitted) VALUES ('${rest_name}', ${o_rating}, ${price}, ${taste}, ${experience}, '${description}', '${city}', '${state_code}', '1', FALSE);`);
            res.status(200).json({message: response, body: req.body})
        } catch (error){
            res.status(500).json({ message: error })
        }
    }

}
```

## pages/api/auth/[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth"
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const authOptions = {
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      authorization: {
        params: {
          prompt: "consent",
          access_type: "offline",
          response_type: "code"
        }
      }
    })
  ]
}
export default NextAuth(authOptions)
```

## Error

```
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error decryption operation failed {
  message: 'decryption operation failed',
  stack: 'JWEDecryptionFailed: decryption operation failed\n' +
    '    at gcmDecrypt (/Users/sammadden/Documents/GitHub/sophs-next-app/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/runtime/decrypt.js:67:15)\n' +
    '    at decrypt (/Users/sammadden/Documents/GitHub/sophs-next-app/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/runtime/decrypt.js:92:20)\n' +
    '    at flattenedDecrypt (/Users/sammadden/Documents/GitHub/sophs-next-app/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwe/flattened/decrypt.js:143:52)\n' +
    '    at async compactDecrypt (/Users/sammadden/Documents/GitHub/sophs-next-app/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwe/compact/decrypt.js:18:23)\n' +
    '    at async jwtDecrypt (/Users/sammadden/Documents/GitHub/sophs-next-app/node_modules/jose/dist/node/cjs/jwt/decrypt.js:8:23)\n' +
    '    at async Object.decode (/Users/sammadden/Documents/GitHub/sophs-next-app/node_modules/next-auth/jwt/index.js:66:7)\n' +
    '    at async Object.session (/Users/sammadden/Documents/GitHub/sophs-next-app/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/session.js:43:28)\n' +
    '    at async AuthHandler (/Users/sammadden/Documents/GitHub/sophs-next-app/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:165:27)\n' +
    '    at async getServerSession (/Users/sammadden/Documents/GitHub/sophs-next-app/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:159:19)\n' +
    '    at async unstable_getServerSession (/Users/sammadden/Documents/GitHub/sophs-next-app/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:195:10)\n' +
    '    at async handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./pages/api/reviews/index.js:35:34)',
  name: 'JWEDecryptionFailed'
}
```

Let me know if you need any more information.

I tried to secure an endpoint using `getServerSession(req, res, authOptions)`, but I kept receiving a JWT error.